# Why can't I create a RichTextBox from a reference of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I'm confused with the `RichTextBox` control.

I have a `RichTextBox` control of my `WinForm` with a width of 100px. I want to create one dynamically and then reference the instance.

So, assuming on my `Form` I have a `RichTextBox` called `rtbResult` I would have thought I can do the following:

```
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.Text =  "Hello all";
    rtb.Width = 50;
    rtbResult = rtb;
```

When the code executes, the result is an empty `RichTextBox` on my page, at the original size of 100px (eg, not at width 50).

Please note, in live I'm using text highlighting and as such it must be a `RichTextBox`, the example above is stripped to make the question more concise.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is not so different from this:

```
RichTextBox r1 = new RichTextBox();
r1.Text =  "I am RTB #1";
Controls.Add(r1);

RichTextBox r2 = new RichTextBox();
r2.Text =  "I am RTB #2";
```

Now on your page you have the `RichTextBox` named `r1`. If you do this:

```
r1 = r2;
```

You do not replace the control in the form with the new `RichTextBox`, you simply assign the same reference to the variable `r1`. In your form you still have the *old* control but both variables (`r1` and `r2`) point to the same object.

What you may do, if you can't simply update the original `RichTextBox` with new values, is to delete the old one and to add the new one in the same position:

```
r2.Bounds = r1.Bounds;
Controls.Remove(r1);
Controls.Add(r2);
```

This is pretty naive, many properties may need to be copied from the old one to the new one (`Dock`, `TabIndex` and so on), moreover the order is important too so you may need to call `Controls.SetChildIndex()` for proper positioning (this depends on what you really have to do and how your code is).

Answer (score 2):

The `rtbResult` is just a variable that contains a reference to the control, it's not the control itself. By putting the new control in that variable you are only changing the variable, the original control is still in the form, and the new control doesn't belong to any form so it's not visible anywhere.

You have to add the new control to the form to make it visible, for example:

```
somePanel.Controls.Add(rtb);
```